# Understanding PHP assignments

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement, mysqli

I am having some issues trying to grasp the idea behind certain lines of code that may be above me at this moment since I am fairly sure they have to do with OOP(something that I don't know much about as I am just starting on the concept behind OOP)This came to me as I was readig a PHP book.The code is as follows.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('example','example','example');
if(!$mysqli){
    die("Could not connect".mysql_error());
}
else {
    echo("Connection established");
}

if($mysqli->query("CREATE DATABASE querycreation1")===TRUE){
    echo"<p>Database Querycreation1 created</p>";
}
else {
    echo "Error creating database".mysql_error();
}
```

I understand the first couple of lines(and appreciate input on best practices),but the part that I am having issues is after the next set of if-else statements.
The second if statement checks if the creation of a database is true,but can someone explain at what time exactly was the database created? do I need  to create one and then check for it in the future? Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is error in the code as you are using the mysqli and there is function `mysql_error` that will give error. Perhaps you have not check the code properly.

Comment: Not strictly! The second __executes__ a `CREATE DATABASE` statement, and then tests if that statement executed successfully

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ the code checks out, there is no error, if you tried running it as is and got an error is more than likely because I changed the first statement to 'example','example','example' :)

Comment: Some prefer to first execute a query and then check it's results in a seperate line. Makes it a bit more readable, as you yourself just saw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comparison in PHP first all expressions get evaluated. This means that in

```
if($mysqli->query("CREATE DATABASE querycreation1")===TRUE)
```

PHP will first run the query() function on the $mysql-object. That function returns a result. In the case of successfull creating a database it will return TRUE (https://www.php.net/mysqli_query). The result of calling this function (TRUE) is then compared to TRUE.

Perhaps more verbose for you to see this:

```
$databaseCreated = $mysqli->query("CREATE DATABASE querycreation1");

if($databaseCreated ===TRUE){
    echo"<p>Database Querycreation1 created</p>";
}
else {
    echo "Error creating database".mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: this is just what I was looking for!!.I had a faint idea of the workings of it and you confirmed it wonderfully.Now, for future reference, would you say that it is better to write it in a more verbose way?

Comment: I'd go with the more verbose is this case, it confuses me less... :)

Answer (score 1):

`$mysqli->query()` performs the query, in this case, a `CREATE` query. The function then returns `TRUE` if the query was executed successfully and `FALSE` if an error occurred. So the database is created exactly at the time the first argument to the `===` comparison is evaluated.

Generally, creating databases in `php` scripts won't happen often, usually only in "installation" scripts use to setup some `php` driven piece of software (such as a discussion board/forum). Other than that, you'll want to create the databases once either through a database management system such as `phpMyAdmin` or a script you delete afterwards. Then in your actual site scripts, you just assume the databases exist because you also usually don't just delete them.

You could write it differently by assigning the return value of the query to a variable and checking against that:

```
$success = $mysqli->query("CREATE DATABASE querycreation1");
if ($success===TRUE){
    // ...
```

But that's purely a matter of preference.

Also, the first else is not strictly necessary because of the `die` statement. There is a number of ways you could simplify (or let's say modify) that part:

```
// The "just no else" version
if (!$mysqli)
    die("Could not connect".mysql_error());
echo("Connection established");

// The one-liner version
if (!$mysqli) die("Could not connect".mysql_error());
echo("Connection established");

// The short-circuit version
$mysqli OR die("Could not connect".mysql_error());
echo("Connection established");

// same using the symbolic version of OR
$mysqli || die("Could not connect".mysql_error());
echo("Connection established");

// you can also include that in the first call
$mysqli = new mysqli('example','example','example') OR die("Could not connect".mysql_error());
echo("Connection established");
```

The last three examples work based on the fact that `php` handles logical operators in a short-circuit way, that is, if the first part is `TRUE`, then the entire `OR` expression will be `TRUE` no matter what the second argument is, so `php` doesn't even bother evaluating it. If the first part is `FALSE`, however, the expression's value depends on the second argument, so it is evaluated.

Comment: Thank you, I had a faint idea of how this was supposed to work.I am curious,since I am just starting, are there other languages that do things like this? and what is the technical name for this sort of assignment evaluation?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a technical name for it, but what's happening internally is using a return value directly instead of assigning it to a variable first. This removes the possibility to access that value later, but saves memory because it's not stored permanently. You can do this in most languages.

Comment: That is great to know.I learned a lot from your post.One thing that I noticed is the explanation on how php handles logical operators.I am guessing that short-circuit way in which it(php)evaluates the operators could bring many problems if one does not pay attention.I will keep this in mind.

Comment: It's mainly good to know because some people (myself included) like using this behavior in the way my last 3 examples do. If you're not aware of the short-circuiting behavior, reading code written this way will confuse you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Point one:
You are creating an instance of a class mysqli which contains methods to connect, query, manage database. You need to pass some parameters which are used by the class'es constructor to connect to the database.

This instance is called an object and now this object has the connection and can use the methods from the class to query, manage that database.

For better understanding:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: I think an instance of a class is an object? What would you say is the difference between an object and an instance of a class?

Comment: Just quoting from above answer : "This instance is called an object"

Comment: You are litterally saying "You're not creating an object, you're creating something which is called an object."

Comment: @scenia No, i believe he is a novice. So, i'm trying to explain him, that and instance of a class is called an object

Comment: Yeah, but the first thing you've written there is "You are not creating an object". Then you explain what he's creating and go on to tell him that this is called an object. That's a contradiction, and my previous comment reduced your post to show that. To check yourself, replace the entire explanation starting with `an instance` up to `database` with `something`, then replace `This instance ...` with `which ...`. You'll get exactly my quote from above.

Comment: That's better :) Although it still doesn't really answer the question and would be better as a comment...